# Why is this inequality regarding squares true?

Tags: inequality

Let, $x,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Then,
$$x^2 < b \iff |x| < \sqrt{b}?$$

Any easy way to see why this is true? Thanks.

Comment: It's false, for example $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2<\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{1}{2}>\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: @Lulu, Sorry I forgot the sqrt sign at the end.

Comment: The square root function increases montonically, and $x^2=b\iff |x|=\sqrt b$.

Comment: You must assume $b\ge 0$ in your statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine you are assuming that $b\geq 0$:
$$x^2<b\Leftrightarrow x^2<\sqrt{b}^2\Leftrightarrow x^2-\sqrt{b}^2<0\Leftrightarrow (x-\sqrt b)(x+\sqrt b)<0$$

Hence $-\sqrt b<x<\sqrt b \Leftrightarrow |x|<\sqrt b.$